# Insert on sqlite database don't generate Primary Key

Tags: android, database, sqlite, primary-key, auto-increment

In my current android project, when I try insert a value in my sqlite database, through this sql statement:

```
insert into Usuario(nome, sobrenome, email, login, senha) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

the row is inserted without a value for the primary key. I have an column id, which according to this [link](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html), it's an alias to ROWID, and should be filled automatically, what it's not happening.

the code where this insertion is performed it's that:

```
  public void insert(String[] data) {
    try {
      Model object = clazz.newInstance();
      List<String> lista = object.getFields();

      List<String> campos = new ArrayList<String>();
      for(int i=1; i<lista.size(); i++)
        campos.add(lista.get(i));

      List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
      for(int i=0; i<campos.size(); i++)
        values.add("?");

      String scampos = campos.toString().replace("[", "(").replace("]", ")");
      String svalues = values.toString().replace("[", "(").replace("]", ")");
      String INSERT = "insert into " + clazz.getSimpleName() + scampos + " values "+ svalues;
      System.out.println("===== INSERT -> "+INSERT);

      SQLiteDatabase db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
      SQLiteStatement insertStmt = db.compileStatement(INSERT);

      for(int i=0; i<data.length; i++)
        insertStmt.bindString(i+1, data[i]);

      insertStmt.executeInsert();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

anyone knows what I am doing wrong here? I can't figure out what is the problem.

**UPDATE**

After read the marked answer, I verify the code for creating the table:

```
Model object = clazz.newInstance();
String CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " + this.getClazz().getSimpleName() + object.dbFields().toString().replace("[", "(").replace("]", ")");
System.out.println(CREATE);
db.execSQL( CREATE );
```

and found the method `dbFields` don't include the PRIMARY KEY attribute for the id column. I fix this and now the problem is solved.

Comment: Could you post your create table statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [linked page](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) says that you get autoincrementing only for an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column.

The [page linked from there](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid) is evem more explicit:

> A PRIMARY KEY column only becomes an integer primary key if the declared type name is exactly "INTEGER". Other integer type names like "INT" or "BIGINT" or "SHORT INTEGER" or "UNSIGNED INTEGER" causes the primary key column to behave as an ordinary table column with integer affinity and a unique index, not as an alias for the rowid.

Answer (score -1):

You can verify if your database table has 'Auto-increment' option activated on its primary key...

Comment: How I can verify that? and in case it's not activated, how I could activate?

Comment: default behaviour is auto-increament

Answer (score -1):

you have to set your column `_id` as primary key - you would have missed that. default behavior of primary key(when it is defined as INTEGER) is auto increment

in schema definition use  `[_id] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,`

Comment: Not all primary keys are autoincrementing. And it is not required to name it `_id`.

Comment: yes.. i mean integer primary key only.. I have given the definition as well. Now i added the same again in brackets.. thanks